# What does 'nvd3dumx.dll' do and why is it the reason my executable is crashing with detached multithreading?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, dll

I have been working a while on a project now and I still cannot seem to resolve this nasty error which comes out of the blue.

My concept of swapping from a game menu/starting screen to a game screen goes the following:

game start -> initialize -> loop menu( read mouse/key input -> render items on screen )

now when the user sets up all information to generate his game the program will launch a child thread which generates/allocates all data and the user will be sent into the loading loop. 
While the worker thread is not done loading, the User is stuck in loop loading which is essentially just cleaning the event buffer from the window + render some fancy image.

Between the input - render sequence there is a miniature function which checks if the loading thread is done. If it is indeed done. It will send the user to the game.

Now without doing a worker thread this would all be no problem. Except for the obvious fact that the loading loop will never be rendered. I've tried compiling and running it on Ubuntu instead of Windows 8 and on there it also works on a child worker thread. 
Everytime the worker thread is finished / almost finished the executable crashes with the module nvd3dumx.dll throwing an error. I've tried g++, VC++ and on all compilers it results in the same error.
The weird thing is that the loading thread's flag for completion might not even be set (after a debugging cout which only sometimes gets called).

I am not sure how to handle this problem and if someone would be able to explain to me what might cause nvd3dumx.dll to crash I would be very glad. I am using a nVidia GeForce graphics card and an intel cpu

Comment: Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: Looks like part of the nvidia GPU drivers. Specifically for 3d.

Comment: I'm quite sure that it's the 3d GPU drivers, but I am not certain of why that should play any role while only using SDL2.
And to be fair I haven't really looked into my program in a debugger since I am still learning assembly language. The Visual Studio C++ Debugger gave out an unknown source (empty tab with dll name as title), because it does not know where the error occurs

Comment: Do you call rendering functions from the thread? Maybe the underlying rendering engine is not thread safe

Comment: I do not use rendering on screen, but I indeed use functions like SDL_CreateSurface, SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface the texture creation does indeed need a renderer which I use the same as the one I render in the meantime for. The thing is that I even tried removing all sdl rendercopys from the main thread, but render present was still active. I'm going to take a look at this

Comment: It really was the fact that SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface used the same renderer that was being used on SDL_RenderPresent in the main thread. But how should I prevent this from happening again. A mutex?